# Build a Forum in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forum

Is there a tutorial or a VERY simple forum dll on how to build a forum from an ASP.NET MVC application? I am trying to publish a site for a semester project, but a requirement is that it must have a forum.

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you need to build one as the content of that project or do you need it as part of a site for managing your semester project??

Comment: @Juri: what you ask is irrelevant, the OP seems to just want to know how to build a forum.

Comment: http://openforum.codeplex.com/

Comment: As Paul Creasey says, I would recommend OpenForum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenForum is a plugable forum module for ASP.NET MVC applications. OpenForum allows you to quickly add a forum to any MVC application with almost no setup/configuration required. OpenForum is highly customizable and extremely flexable.
http://openforum.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is Openforum still available?  last update was 2009.  Surely there is another a more recent one?

Comment: I think this project is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon a modern implementation on github. It supports dotnet 5
and AspNet Core. I myself have not yet used it but it sure looks promissing considering that forums are a thing of the past (not taking into account that SO is a forum ..sort of :) https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/POPForums